# How do I limit the results of this MySQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am unable to add the LIMIT variable to the following code. I am trying to just display the first record, but when I add "LIMIT 1" after the .$gid part of the code, I get an error. I have tried every variable. I am also not sure why the " space period $gid is formatted like it is.

```
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `loan_real_types` WHERE fKeyGroup = " . $gid;
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "" . $results['name'] . "";
}

?>
```

Ultimately, I am just trying to display the first record of the table where fkeyGroup is a match.

Comment: [Lest we forget Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: add [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html) on your SQL clause :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably just forgot to add space before `LIMIT` which would cause an error.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `loan_real_types` WHERE fKeyGroup = " . $gid . " LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: I now works perfectly! Amazing. What do the periods do around the $gid? Previously, there was not one after $gid. The comma's and periods always mess me up.

Comment: The period is a concatenation operator. It allows you to piece together strings and variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `loan_real_types` WHERE fKeyGroup = " . $gid . " LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
// just use if here
if ($results = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "" . $results['name'] . "";
}
```